# Как заменить несколько картинок на одну?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Причем, необходимо спрятать старые картинки. Потому что я работаю с их атрибутами.

```
for (var i=0; i<6; i++) {

 $('#kartsSoper').prepend(array[razdacha2[i]]).hide();
 $('#kartsSoper').prepend($('#rubaha ')).css('position','relative').show()

}
```

Таким образом не получается.

Answer (score 1):

Ок, попробуй сделать так. Хм... Первое что пришло в голову. Исходник скачать можно 
[отсюда](http://narod.ru/disk/32126758001/changeCard.rar.html).

```
<html>
    <style>
        .hidden {display: none;}
        .open {display: inline;}
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        var razdacha2 = new Array(3);
        razdacha2[0] = '<img class="hidden" src="testImage/6.png" />';
        razdacha2[1] = '<img class="hidden" src="testImage/7.png" />';
        razdacha2[2] = '<img class="hidden" src="testImage/8.png" />';
        var rubaha = '<img class="open rubaha" src="testImage/rubaha.png" />';
    //Раздача карт из массива
        function PlayOut()
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                $('#kartsSoper').append(razdacha2[i]);
                $('#kartsSoper').append(rubaha);
            }
        }
        // нажатие левой кнопкой мыши по карте
        $('.open').live('click', function()
        {
            var thisCard = $(this);
            if (!thisCard.hasClass('rubaha')) //Если не рубаха, то открывает рубаху, //а карту закрывает; Если рубаха, то открывает карту, скрывает рубаху
            {
                thisCard.next().removeClass('hidden')
                                .addClass('open');
                thisCard.removeClass('open')
                        .addClass('hidden');    
            }
            else
            {
                thisCard.prev().removeClass('hidden')
                                .addClass('open');
                thisCard.removeClass('open')
                        .addClass('hidden');    
            }

        });

    </script>

    <body>
            <button onclick="javascript: PlayOut()">Разложить</button> <br />
            <div id="kartsSoper">

            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Еще можно попробовать Jquery функцию: detach([selector])
Удаляет выбранные элементы на странице. В качестве параметра можно указать селектор и тогда удалены будут только те выбранные элементы, которые ему удовлетворяют. Особенность заключается в том, что при использовании detach, jQuery не удаляет информацию о элементе и поэтому он может быть восстановлен. Например:

```
var foo = jQuery('#foo');

foo.detach(); //удаляем элемент

//много-много кода

foo.appendTo('body'); //вставляем элемент обратно на страницу (не обязательно в то же место, где он был)
```

Comment: картинки хранятся в массиве array
я их вывожу в блок kartsSoper, и работаю с атрибутами этих картинок.
Но мне нужно, чтобы вместо этих картинок была видна другая картинка. 
(пишу игру в карты, нужно, чтобы вместо карт показывались их рубашки.)

Comment: Поправил код. Возможно не очень грамотно сделал. Если есть другие мысли, отпишитесь.